# Vector from String causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a string into a vector. My code is:

```
char **my_str2vect(char *str)
{
    char** vect;
    char* temp;
    int num_whitespaces = 0;

    temp = str;

    for(; *temp!= '\0'; temp++)
    {
        if(*temp == ' ')
        {
            num_whitespaces++;
        }
    }

    vect = (char **)malloc((num_whitespaces+1)*sizeof(char *));

    *vect = str;

    for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
    {
        if(*str == ' ')
        {
             *str = '\0';
             *vect = ++str;
             vect++;
        }
    }

    *vect = NULL;

    return vect;
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting segmentation faults. I call the function using the following code:

```
n = read(0, buffer, MAX-1);
buffer[MAX] = '\0';

if(n >= 0)
{
     vect = my_str2vect(buffer);
}
```

Comment: how about `if (n >=0) buffer[n] = 0;` instead of buffer[MAX] ? BTW: the `*vect = ++str;` does not look right either (it could point to a space) better drop an anchor on the first non-space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'vect' in your question, as this code seems to be attempting to split a string along its whitespace into an array of strings

Comment: If your intention is to split that string into whitespace-separated tokens you may have a rude awakening with your existing algorithm if/when you're presented with strings like `" This   is  a string. "` (note the leading whitespace and/or multiple spaces embedded within).

Comment: Use `strtok`!! That's what it was meant for!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Boost has a string library which does exactly this. As WhozCraig pointed out, your code has other bugs as well. Boost is well-tested and more likely to work correctly given edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several bugs in your code:
1. In your `my_str2vect` function, the pointer `vect` is moved to the end of your allocated memory, so when you return vect and would like to use something `vect[1]` or `vect[2]` in the caller function, there must be segment faults. You may use a `vect_tmp` to store the original position before starting to operate on `vect`.
2. Some logical error when you start converting the string. Please refer to my modified code below.

```
char **my_str2vect(char *str)
{
    char** vect;
    char** vect_tmp;
    char* temp;
    int num_whitespaces = 0;

    temp = str;

    for(; *temp!= '\0'; temp++)
    {
        if(*temp == ' ')
        {
            num_whitespaces++;
        }
    }

    vect_tmp = (char **)malloc((num_whitespaces+1)*sizeof(char *));
    vect = vect_tmp;

    *vect = str;

    for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
    {
        if(*str == ' ')
        {
             *str = '\0';
             *(++vect) = str + 1;
        }
    }

    *(++vect) = NULL;

    return vect_tmp;
}
```

Please note that even after modification, this function still can't deal with some special situations with continuous spaces. You may spend more time on it to improve the compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating only the vector, but not each case of your vector. You can use `calloc` for that.